# Not found server name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have searched for 2 days for a solution to this problem, but I can't find anything. Please help me. My computer can't find Server Name for SQL Server.

Server name is empty in this picture below.

[image: HERE SERVER NAME, BUT IT IS EMPTY]

Answer (score 0):

You should check from menu Start > Type `SQL Server Configuration Manager`.

1. Choose `SQL Server Services`. If you can't find like: `SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS)` or `SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)` go to step 3.
2. If this appears like:

[image]

Check `State`. If it `Running` right click to `SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS)` or `SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)` > Restart.

If it `Stopped` or anything. Please right click and press `Start`.

Make sure `SQL Server Browser` also `Running`.

3. If you still can't find server name. Please install again SQL Server in [this link(choose SQL version you want to use, that I using SQL Server 2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299)

Note: Please choose: SQLEXPRWT_xversion_ENU.exe this include `ExpressAndTools`